# How to add OffsetLedgerDimension to Fixed Asset Journal by x++?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

By x++, I would like to create a Fixed Asset Journal.

I'm facing to issue about populate `LedgeJournalTrans.offsetDefaultDimension`.

Part of my code:

```
ledgerJournalTrans.OffsetDefaultDimension = ledgerJournalTrans.getOffsetLedgerDimensionForLedgerType(
        AssetLedgerAccounts::assetOffsetLedgerDimension(AssetTable.AssetId, 
        'MyBook', AssetTransType::Depreciation ),curExt());

ledgerJournalTrans.insert();
    
ledgerJournalTrans_Asset.initValue();
ledgerJournalTrans_Asset.RefRecId    = ledgerJournalTrans.RecId;
ledgerJournalTrans_Asset.AssetId     = assetTable.assetId;
ledgerJournalTrans_Asset.TransType   = AssetTransTypeJournal::Depreciation;
ledgerJournalTrans_Asset.BookId      = 'MyBook';        
            
ledgerJournalTrans_asset.insert();
```

I used

```
ledgerJournalTrans.OffsetDefaultDimension = assetBook.DefaultDimension
```

**but NOT work**

I'm not able to get the FixedAsset default Offeset; I would like to copy the behaviour when I add the FixedAsset in Account field.

There is any way?

Example - I would like this behaviour by code:

[image]

I would like to copy in Offset the Fixed Asset Financial Dimension:

[image]

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong field. You should be using `LedgerJournalTrans.LedgerDimension`/`LedgerJournalTrans.OffsetLedgerDimension`

**Not** - `LedgerJournalTrans.DefaultDimension`/`LedgerJournalTrans.OffsetDefaultDimension`

- `DefaultDimension` - This is your normal financial dimensions, minus the ledger bit. In your case, something like `00000031-00000023-00000003`
- `LedgerDimension` - This is the ledger bit + the default dimension. In your case, something like `BUIL-00000031-00000023-00000003`, where the `BUIL` is some sort of account.

There are tons of resources online on how to create a LedgerDimension from a default dimension. You should look at `AxdDimensionUtil` and `DimensionStorage`. Here's one resource - https://www.schweda.net/blog_ax.php?bid=553&wdl=en

Your AssetBook has a DefaultDimension and you need to combine it with a main account to get a LedgerDimension.

Comment: Dear kindly @Alex Kwinty. Please, could you help me how can extract the Financial Dimension from Fixed Asset?

Comment: My post has all the information you need. `assetBook.DefaultDimension` is a `DefaultDimension`, which you already have. You just need to generate your `LedgerDimension` by taking your `DefaultDimension` and adding your main account using the link I sent.